# iOS app written in swift is crashing when returning to a view

Tags: ios, swift

I'm writing an app that loads an options screen (scene 1) where the user will fill in some text fields then segue to a new scene (scene 2). After the user finished with scene 2, the user can click a button which will segue them back to scene 1 to fill out the options again. On scene 1, I'm setting the first text field to become the first responder so the keyboard automatically appears when the view loads.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.numeratorBegin.becomeFirstResponder()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

This works great when the app loads. The keyboard appears and the cursor is in the numeratorBegin text field. However, when the user finishes with scene 2 and presses the button to go back to scene 1, the app crashes. The crash does not occur when the first responder is not being set in viewDidLoad. The debugger shows the following line causing the crash with the message Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(Code=2, address=hexHere)

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
```

The idea is to have the numeratorBegin text field to become the first responder every time the view loads. For the life of me I can't discover why the app is crashing.

Comment: If the user wants to go back you can't use segue for that, you need to dismiss scene 2 from whatever nav controller your in - AKA removing the VC from the memory. If you need to pass data to scene 1 while dismissing scene 2 you need to use unwind to segue in order to achieve that and not the normal segue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding some more points to Alain T.'s answer.

Instead of

`self.numeratorBegin.becomeFirstResponder()` inside `override func viewDidLoad()`

add it to `override func viewWillAppear()`

and `self.numeratorBegin.resignFirstResponder()` inside `override func viewWillDisappear()`

If you try to use becomeFirstResponder()/resignFirstResponder() in other thread, then it causes a crash. So it's better to follow the above methods which always executes in main thread.

Comment: That worked. Thanks for the additional tip on resigning first responder in viewWillDisappear as well.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that becomeFirstResponder sets some internal states/variables that depend on the view hierarchy.   When viewDidLoad() is called, the view hierarchy is not setup yet so these states may be skewed somehow and affect the release cycle of some UI component.

You should call becomeFirstResponder in viewWillAppear instead.  The view hierarchy is ready at that point.